# How secure are ajax based Pinax apps from bots (Mass voting, Mass rating)?

Tags: django, django-apps, pinax

There seem to be many pinax apps that work with ajax using a specific urlpattern for that pinax app.

For example there is the ratings app. It uses ajax.

Normally you'd ajax to the page the product is on. You'd need to get CSRF token from there. So, the user or a bot would actually need to visit the page to rate the product.

So all the security mixins would work.

However pinax uses a url like `site.com/ratings`. Where does this ratings form get the CSRF from? If it can only get it from the product page it is secure, cos we can apply security measures on the page.

How ever if the CSRF is got from the `sites.com/ratings` a bot could easily bypass all the security mixins on the product page and directly mass upvote or downvote or rate the products.

Does it get the CSRF from `site.com/ratings` or the product or view page in which the widget is embedded.

Same goes for likes and similar apps.

TL;DR:

1) Can someone create a bot to mass rate or vote pinax apps like ratings that works without even visiting the product or post or model view and just by visiting the pinax apps URL thus bypassing all security measures placed as a mixin to the product page?

2) Are any security measures takes in the `template tag` so that the ratings ajax works only in the page in which the `template tag` is embedded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the site developer is using middleware to protect all their views.

For example, all our starter projects ship with the `CsrfViewMiddleware` turned on:

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-starter-projects/blob/account/project_name/settings.py#L111

So that takes you to needing to pass along the CSRF token with your ajax request in order for the `post` handler of the views in Pinax ajax views to work.  To do this, you should include something like:

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-starter-projects/blob/account/static/src/js/ajax.js

and

https://github.com/pinax/pinax-starter-projects/blob/account/static/src/js/index.js#L14

In your JS pipeline.  This is based on the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request).

Comment: Please answer this: Would a bot need to visit the page with the template tag of the ratings widget in order to get the CSRF token or can a bot get the CSRF token directly from `site.com/ratings`.

I'm asking this cos if there is a security measure or mixin or IP ban or ratelimiting applied to the view containing the product with rating template it'd wouldn't apply to the ratings app in the later case.

Comment: I'm not talking about rate limiting middleware. Just in the view(maybe as a mixin).

Comment: i.e; can I make a bot that rates just by visting the pinax ratings app url if it know the PK, for example `site.com/ratings`. This bot would not be able to visit any other URL on the site.